# Scala Macro Paradise: How do I get an annotation's arguments using macro annotations?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

Let's say I wanted to replicate an annotation like @specialized(Int)--crazy I know--using macro annotations. Something like:

```
class expand(expanded: Any*) extends Annotation with StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro expand.expandImpl
}

object expand {
 def expandImpl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*):c.Expr[Any] = {        
    // would like to be able to get access to the "expanded" args above.
    ???
  }
}

// Usage:
 def foo[@expand(Int) T] = 4
```

Is there any way to get access to the arguments of the annotation (Int in the example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `c.prefix`. It will contain a tree corresponding to `new expand(Int)`.

Another option is `c.macroApplication` which will be  `new expand(Int).macroTransform(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can fake it by doing something like:

```
class expandArgs(args: Any*) extends Annotation with StaticAnnotation

def foo[@expand @expandArgs(Int) T] = 4
```